# no implicit conversion of Symbol into String, Paperclip + Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am currently working on a rails 4 app offers different subscription packages. I would like to upload images and have them belong to each package. I am using the Amazon S3 to store the photos using the 'aws-sdk' gem.

I know that this has something to do with the :photo symbol being a hash and not a string, but I am not sure what to do to resolve it.

When I submit my form either nested from the package, or by itself, I get the error

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
```

Here are the relevant files. Thanks for the help.

**config/development.rb**

```
# Amazon S3 config for paperclip, required for Heroku, supplemented on development
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :url => :s3_domain_url,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => 'oops',
      :access_key_id => 'bigoops',
      :secret_access_key => 'biggeroops'
    }
  }
```

**models/package_photo.rb**

```
class PackagePhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

**models/package.rb**

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope { order('sort_order') } 

  has_many :package_photos

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :package_photos, :reject_if => proc { |a| a[:photo].nil?}, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**controllers/packages_controller.rb**

```
class PackagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_package, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /packages
  # GET /packages.json
  def index
    @packages = Package.all()
  end

  # GET /packages/1
  # GET /packages/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /packages/new
  def new
    @package = Package.new
  end

  # GET /packages/1/edit
  def edit
    @package.package_photos.build
  end

  # POST /packages
  # POST /packages.json
  def create
    @package = Package.new(package_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @package.save
        format.html { redirect_to @package, notice: 'Package was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @package }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @package.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /packages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /packages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @package.update(package_params)
        format.html { redirect_to packages_url, notice: 'Package was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @package }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @package.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /packages/1
  # DELETE /packages/1.json
  def destroy
    @package.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to packages_url, notice: 'Package was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_package
      @package = Package.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def package_params
      params.require(:package).permit(:title, :price, :description, :package_photos_attributes => [:id, :package_id, :sort_order, :photo, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

**views/packages/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= package_form.fields_for :package_photos do |package_photo| %>
  <div class="media image-form-control">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-file">
        Upload <%= package_photo.file_field :photo, :class => 'form-control'%>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm package-image-delete" type="button">Delete</button>
      <%= package_photo.check_box '_destroy', :class => 'hidden' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Paperclip documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3), for `url` option:

> The value of this option is a string, not a symbol. **right**:
>   ":s3_domain_url" **wrong**: :s3_domain_url

In your code, `url` option is specified as a `Symbol` i.e., `:s3_domain_url` which is *incorrect* and hence resulting in below error

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
```

`url` option value should be specified as a `String` i.e., `":s3_domain_url"` (**Notice** surrounding quotes)

Update the `paperclip defaults` as below:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :url => ":s3_domain_url", ## Notice quotes "" around :s3_domain_url
  :path => "/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", ## Add path option, specify the path as per your requirement 
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => 'oops',
    :access_key_id => 'bigoops',
    :secret_access_key => 'biggeroops'
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**
When specifying `:url` option for `paperclip`, you should also specify the `:path` option.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be simple.